# Reload an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reload

I am very new to JavaScript and I am trying to reload an element (a div) using only Javascript when that div is clicked..

I found the location.reload() function, but this reloads the whole page. That doesnt work for me, because on clicking the button I want to display the time it took to click that div.

I won't put the code because it will overcomplicate the question. I am basically just wondering if there is a function like location.reload() I could use to target a specific element (div) so it reloads.

Update: Here is the code:

```
<h1>Test your Reactions!</h1>
<p>click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can</p>

<p id="timeNeeded"></p>

<div id="circle"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        //defining variables
var myColors = ["green", "blue", "red", "purple", "orange", "black"];
var myShape = ["50px", "inherit"];

var startTime, endTime, timeDiff;
var randColor = myColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length)];
var randShape = myShape[Math.floor(Math.random() * myShape.length)];


// defining function: Setting the color and shape of the box
function setStyle () {

    var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
     circle.style.backgroundColor = randColor;
     circle.style.borderRadius = randShape;
}

// defining function: Set Start time
 function start() {
  startTime = new Date();
}

// defining end function and time difference
function end() {
  endTime = new Date();
}

// starting time measure
start();


//exectute style
setStyle();

// Clicking the button
document.getElementById("circle").onclick = function () {

// reloads the page
// location.reload();


end();
var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

}
  document.getElementById("timeNeeded").innerHTML = "Your reaction: " + timeDiff

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code. how the div is created ? what do you have to reload on it ?

Comment: You can't "reload" a div, you can however, repopulate its contents on demand, so you can make a function to do your "reloading" for you

Comment: you need to use ajax for the partial reloading

Comment: Here is an example of using ajax to update an element in response to a click event: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_httprequest

Comment: Search for and learn [tag:ajax]. [tag:jquery] offers an easy implementation to deal with ajax.

Comment: What you could do is put the original and/or new content of the div in a variable, then just repopulate it using the variable(s), just as casraf has suggested. I've done this myself on a few occasions. Also, can you elaborate about the timer? Do you mean the time between the page originally loaded and when the div was clicked?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I realize I need to do it a different way.

Comment: I don't really understand why I am downvoted twice. I am a total newbie and the answer to my question was a no. Whats the big deal

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for reloading partial constant of the page without reloading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or if you just need to change div content use following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
Text 1
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDiv()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDiv() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Text 1 "  + Math.random(); ;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```